# Is there a built in function for printed text to clear in php?

Tags: php

When you write echo in php "text is printed in the output"
How can you clear it after it is printed?

Comment: `clear`, what do you mean?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. Once the page is rendered, PHP is done executing. But you can hide elements with CSS or Javascript...

Comment: @showdev yeah how can you hide it in php?

Comment: @u_mulder how can u hide written text afer using function echo?

Comment: You can not output it. Or you can output it in an element with a class that's hidden with CSS. Can you show us your code and describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: why not assign it to a variable and then not echo that variable

Comment: Close the browser

Answer (score 0):

Clean (erase) the output buffer

```
// clean the output buffer 
ob_clean();
```

Please refer this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php)

For below example, there is no output on the browser

```
echo 'This is text.';
ob_clean();
```

Comment: the next person debugging this is gonna be very confused why nothing is printed ...

Comment: I might ask the OP, what's the purpose?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl he should debug in the code will found ob_clean()

Comment: @RakeshJakhar im imagining a multi file 2k+ lines php structure here :D

Comment: @jonathanHeindl if someone is debugging, he should debug in PHP file, not on the browser, he will definitely find ob_clean. If he fails to debug he should read more about programming

Comment: It just seems unnecessary and indicates code smell. Without knowing the purpose, it seems more appropriate to comment or remove the `echo`.

Comment: @showdev OP is asking about how to clear the output, after print...its simple why you guys are so confused

Comment: I'm not confused about your answer, I just think it's a bad idea and I want more information from the OP. I can't tell what specifically the OP is trying to accomplish. Why output something that you don't want outputted?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on context. When you run PHP in CLI you can for e.g. execute a shell command to clear it, `shell_exec('clear');`, but on macOS terminal it does not work. Maybe there on other it will.